# How to fix "Cannot read property 'id' of null" error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I am following along the apollo tutorial. The end result is an interactive app that allows logged in users to reserve a spot on an upcoming Space-X launch.

I just finished writing three mutation resolvers: login, bookTrips and cancelTrip. 
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers.html#mutation

Testing bookTrips with an object array of 3 IDs as an argument results in an error. 
https://graphqlbin.com/v2/K1V7ir

Testing login resolver works
https://graphqlbin.com/v2/K1V7ir

Testing cancelTrip works
https://graphqlbin.com/v2/K1V7ir

I've gone through my code a few times looking for a typo. I commented out my version of the code and copy/pasted the code given from the tutorial still get the same error.

inside src/resolvers.js

```
bookTrips: async (_, { launchIds }, { dataSources }) => {
        const results = await dataSources.userAPI.bookTrips({ launchIds });
        const launches = await dataSources.launchAPI.getLaunchesByIds({
            launchIds,
        });

        return {
            success: results && results.length === launchIds.length,
            message: results.length === launchIds.length
                ? 'trips booked successfully'
                : `the following launches could not be booked: ${launchIds.filter(
                    id => !results.includes(id),
                )}`,
            launches,
        };
    },
cancelTrip: async (_, { launchId }, { dataSources }) => {
        const result = dataSources.userAPI.cancelTrip({ launchId });

        if (!result) 
            return {
                success: false,
                message: 'failed to cencel trip',
            };

        const launch = await dataSources.launchAPI.getLaunchById({ launchId });
        return {
            success: true,
            message: 'trip cancelled',
            launches: [launch],
        };
    },
},
```

inside src/datasources/launch.js

```
// returns several launches based on their respective launchIds
getLaunchByIds({ launchIds }) {
    return Promise.all(
        launchIds.map(launchId => this.getLaunchById({ launchId })),
    );
}

// method takes in a flight number and returns the data for a particular launch
    async getLaunchById({ launchId }) {
        const res = await this.get('launches', { flight_number: launchId });
        return this.launchReducer(res[0]);
    }

// transform launch data into a shape the schema expects
    launchReducer(launch) {
        return {
            id: launch.flight_number || 0,
            cursor: `${launch.launch_date_unix}`,
            site: launch.launch_site && launch.launch_site.site_name,
            mission: {
                name: launch.mission_name,
                missionPatchSmall: launch.links.mission_patch_small,
                missionPatchLarge: launch.links.mission_patch,
            },
            rocket: {
                id: launch.rocket.rocket_id,
                name: launch.rocket.rocket_name,
                type: launch.rocket.rocket_type,
            },
        };
    }
```

inside src/datasources/user.js

```
 // Takes an object with an array of launchIds and books them for the logged in user
 async bookTrips({ launchIds }) {
  const userId = this.context.user.id;
   if (!userId) return;

   let results = [];

// for each launch id, try to book the trip and add it to the results array
// if successful
for (const launchId of launchIds) {
  const res = await this.bookTrip({ launchId });
  if (res) results.push(res);
}

return results;
```

}

After runnning this in my graphql playground

```
 mutation BookTrips {
  bookTrips(launchIds: [67,68,69]) {
   success
   message
   launches {
    id
   }
  }
 }
```

I am expecting a success message and and the ids of the mutations I just booked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the user is not found. Try changing

```
async bookTrips({ launchIds }) {
    const userId = this.context.user.id;
```

to

```
async bookTrips({ launchIds }) {
    const userId = this.context.user && this.context.user.id;
```

Comment: Doing this throws a new error: "dataSources.launchAPI.getLaunchesByIds is not a function"

Comment: I had a typo... inside my src/datasources/launch.js I defined it as getLaunchByIds and not getLaunchesByIds. My bad for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I ran into the same error when trying to use Apollo to send authorization params in headers with something like:

```
  const currentUserJSON = localStorage.getItem("currentUser") || undefined;
  const currentUser =
    currentUserJSON !== undefined ? JSON.parse(currentUserJSON) : undefined;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      ...(currentUser !== undefined
        ? { [`Authorization-User-ID`]: currentUser.id }
        : {}),
    },
  };
});
```

Turned out the bug was that I was checking whether localStorage returned undefined, when it returns null for no data.

Therefore my logic was trying to read `currentUser.id` when currentUser was `null`.

Simple solution:

```
// Cast nulls to undefined when fetching from localStorage
localStorage.getItem("currentUser") || undefined;
```